# Changing height and position of multiple div's in order depending on scroll position

Tags: jquery, css, html

I'm currently creating a one-page scrolling website, with several divs. On scrolling, these divs then change height and position using jQuery to create a parallax effect.

I've made a quick [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/alexanderjsp/tH46U/2/) of what I'm trying to achieve, this example has two divs. However, if I was to add more divs (5 or 6), then I'm not sure how I would code that in jQuery.

When the green div is at the top of the page and it's height is equal to 100% of the document height, then I want a third div to scroll in. So effectively, the green div should act as the red div once it's full height. I know I could do this using a load of if/else's, determining whether the document height is equal to something, but is there a cleaner way of doing this?

Here's what I have at the moment in terms of jQuery, but I'm not sure where to go from here:

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
    cs = $(document).scrollTop();
    $('.base').css({'height':700-cs});
    $('.one').css({'height':cs, 'top':700-cs});
})
```

Comment: You may want to use the CSS animation, check this out I think this should help you

Answer (score 0):

I have something that will take you halfway by doing this:

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
    cs = $(document).scrollTop();
    $('.base').css({'height': 700-cs});
    $('.one').css({'height': 1400-cs});
    $('.two').css({'height': 2100-cs});
});
```

In combination with this changed CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    height:4000px;
}
div.item {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:red;
    max-height:700px;
}
div.item.one {
    top:100%;
    height:0;
    background:green;
}
div.item.two {
    bottom:0;
    height:0;
    background:blue;
    display: block;
}
img {
    right:50%;
    top:50%;
}
```

Positioning the images is now up to you.